# Expression meaning crying in reaction to beauty

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, idioms, synonyms

Is there a word or phrase that means **crying because of beauty** or crying in reaction to beauty?

Comment: I vote for closing because the question is unclear.

Comment: It is unclear whether you want to know an expression for the beauty that causes the crying or an expression that means "crying because of beauty" Your subject title does not match your question.

Comment: @LittleEva your edit has made the title ask a different question to the body.

Comment: Edited to resolve conflict introduced in first edit.

Comment: In a question worded in terms of cause and effect, the question was about effect. You worded the title to ask about cause.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good question about a complex experience.

At times beauty just seems to overwhelm me – breaks my heart – and I’ve never found a better way to express that experience then to say it was ‘*bittersweet*.’ Why can great beauty bring tears and leave me feeling *bittersweet*? Perhaps because beauty can be so transient, so evanescent ... and I can't bear its passing, or the thought of living without it. On another level, maybe the experience reminds me of my own ... transience.

---

> [**bittersweet**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/bittersweet) *adjective*
>   1.1. Arousing pleasure tinged with sadness or pain: ‘the room, with all its *bittersweet* memories’; (Oxford Dictionaries)

---

> "In brevity lies passion's birth, not long this flower for the earth. Life's blossom is but for a season. Passion calls this passing, treason."---LE

Comment: We can be "moved to tears" by great beauty, or "cry tears of joy," but there is no actual element of pain or sadness that must be present along with the joy or pleasure, for something to be bittersweet.  Looking at old family vacation pictures (just for an example) would be pleasurable remembering the fun you had together. The sadness could be that a loved one is no longer around and you can't do these things with them ever again. So we treasure our family albums and it a mix of pleasure a pain when we page through them. That is bitersweet.

Comment: You can also laugh so hard, tears can flow. There is no element of sadness or pain, so this is not a bittersweet emotion.

Comment: You need to read my whole sentence. Of course it makes no sense when you lop the first half off.

Comment: I was referring to the OP's question about beauty that moves one to tears.  I meant *that* emotion is one of joy/pleasure, but it does not involve pain or sorrow. So it is *not* bittersweet. Hopefully this clarifies my examples for you now. Bittersweet means a mix of pain and pleasure, not just joy.

Answer (score 1):

You might call that thing that brings one to tears **Stendhalish**, coined from the eponymous [Stendhal Syndrome](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Stendhal+Syndrome). While it is first defined as being *psychosomatic* a disorder, it is described this way:

> The term can also be used to describe a similar reaction when confronted with immense beauty in the natural world.

While psychologists might debate whether Stendhal syndrome is a real and debilitating disorder, we can still use the terminology to to describe something that evokes such a reaction.

**Tears of joy** and other negative reactions to something positive (crying because of beauty) would fit, and Stendhal syndrome is mentioned in this context in the book [Pictures and Tears: A History of People Who Have Cried in Front of Paintings](https://books.google.com/books?id=6eQ6a-JozocC&pg=PA34&lpg=PA34&dq=tears%20and%20stendhal%20syndrome&source=bl&ots=U5QTxet8Ah&sig=TJ0Q8sGEDpkNv6-zG1iOlVAliaM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ntWeVaqJKI2zoQSIxJeYBg&ved=0CDUQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=tears%20and%20stendhal%20syndrome&f=false) (by James Elkins).

*[Tears of joy](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2831275/Why-cry-happiness-revealed-Responding-negative-reaction-helps-people-cope-extreme-joy.html)* is a common expression for crying while experiencing a happy emotion. (Daily Mail / Science and Technology)